# How to do the live streaming of music channels on my site?

Tags: 7

I am about to work on internet radio site.How am gonna do the functionality live streaming of channels.Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using [Live Streaming](https://www.drupal.org/project/vls) module.

[How to use?](http://www.videowhisper.com/?p=Drupal%20Live%20Streaming%20Module)